# Google Fonts API not working on FF 3.6.25 (Mac)

Tags: firefox, google-font-api

No fonts with Google Fonts are working on Firefox 3.6.25 (Mac). This seems to be an issue with the API itself—the Google Fonts website does not even show the fonts properly.

Does anyone have a solution for this? Can you confirm that the fonts will not display properly?

Comment: im having the same problem. do you able to solve this problem?